# Как получить hex

Tags: php

Есть небольшой код:

```
function raw2hex($raw) {
    $m = unpack('H*', $raw);
    return $m[1];
}

function hex2raw($hex) {
    return pack('H*', $hex);
}

$bin = hex2raw(0x32 . 0x2B . 0x32);//2+2
$hex = raw2hex($bin);
print $hex;
```

Возвращается строка из дестичных кодов (504350).
А мне нужно получить hex-коды(0x32,0x2B,0x32).
Уже несколько часов бьюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hex($s) { 
     $v = unpack('H*', $s); 
   return chunk_split($v[1], 2, ' '); 
} 
function unhex($s) {  
   return  pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $s));
}
```